# Address from `amsart` changes last empty `\paragraph{}`

Tags: sections-paragraphs, amsart, addresses

Using `amsart` class I noticed today a strange output if we end the file with a `\paragraph{}`.

In this case this last paragraph became part of the address since it is inserted just in front of it and also with other font.

I know that we can solve this simply insert empty space after it (so that line is not empty). Also I know that one could ask *why to end with such paragraph?* but I am just asking to learn with this strange output.

I think that a kind of *clearparagraph* would be nice in this case so the address would start a new block.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\address{Address}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Foo

\paragraph{Paragraph here}

\paragraph{Another paragraph here}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fix:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\preto\@setaddresses{\if@noskipsec\mbox{}\fi}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\address{Address}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

Foo

\paragraph{Paragraph here}

\paragraph{Another paragraph here}

\end{document}
```

However, `\paragraph{...}` without any following text is bad input anyway.

The conditional `\if@noskipsec` is true when LaTeX has absorbed a sectional title and is waiting for the first paragraph after it. With the fix, if at the time the addresses are printed the conditional is still true, we emit `\mbox{}`, which provides the required text (that triggers printing the sectional title, in case it's inline) and so the `\par` issued by `\@setaddresses` is effective.

Comment: I know it is bad input. But the paper is in progress and so I close it with empty paragraph and then observed this. Anyway, nice solution. Thanks.